# Choose specific plan(answer) according to the selected answer by the user

Tags: javascript, php, html, logic

There are 20+ option that the user needs to select and based on the selected option specific answer needs to be returned.
how do I filter the options selected by the user and display the apropriate answer

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WEB Plan</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Plan Calculator</h1>
        <hr>
        <form align="center">
            Question Type : How many devices are using the internet?
            <select>
                <option>How many devices are using the internet?</option>
                <option id="internet_use" value="4">1-4</option>
                <option id="internet_use" value="10">5-10</option>
                <option id="internet_use" value="15">10-15</option>
                <option id="internet_use" value="20">15+</option>
            </select><br>
            Question Type : How often do you video conference?
            <select>
                <option>How often do you video conference?</option>
                <option id="video" value="Daily">Daily</option>
                <option id="video" value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option id="video" value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
            </select><br>
            Question Type : Does your household game online?
            <select>
                <option>Does your household game online?</option>
                <option id="game" value="Daily">Daily</option>
                <option id="game" value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option id="game" value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <!-- <div>
            Suggested Plan : ....
        </div> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery : create a function that returns [,...] based on your filter.
React : do not render according to the filter.